# Cannot trigger button save after adding tier

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, button

I want to make the user can input value for multiple tiers. The HTML coding is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="logo.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <style>
        .tier-container{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: wrap;
        }
        .sites-container,
        .users-container,
        .skus-container {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: 2%;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .calc-container {
            white-space: nowrap; 
        }
        input[type="number"] {
            width: 60px; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="license-config-container">
        <h1>License Configuration</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="cost-container">
        <h1>Cost Calculator</h1>
        <form id="calculatorForm">
            <div class="input-cost-container">
                <label for="base_cost">Base Cost:</label><input type="text" id="base_cost" name="base_cost">
                <label for="qty_sites">Sites:</label><input type="number" id="qty_sites" name="qty_sites">
                <label for="qty_users">Users:</label><input type="number" id="qty_users" name="qty_users">
                <label for="qty_skus">SKUs:</label><input type="number" id="qty_skus" name="qty_skus">
            </div>
            <div class="tier-container">
                <div id="sitesContainer" class="sites-container">
                    <p>Sites</p>
                    <div class="sites-tier">
                            <input type="number" name="tier_minimum_sites[]" required id="tier_minimum_sites_0"> - 
                            <input type="number" name="tier_maximum_sites[]" required id="tier_maximum_sites_0"> RM 
                            <input type="text" name="tier_cost_sites[]" id="tier_cost_sites_0">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" onclick="addSitesTier(this)"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="usersContainer" class="users-container">
                    <p>Users</p>
                    <div class="users-tier">
                            <input type="number" name="tier_minimum_users[]" required id="tier_minimum_users_0"> - 
                            <input type="number" name="tier_maximum_users[]" required id="tier_maximum_users_0"> RM 
                            <input type="text" name="tier_cost_users[]" id="tier_cost_users_0">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" onclick="addUsersTier(this)"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="skusContainer" class="skus-container">
                    <p>SKUs</p>
                    <div class="skus-tier">
                            <input type="number" name="tier_minimum_skus[]" required id="tier_minimum_skus_0"> - 
                            <input type="number" name="tier_maximum_skus[]" required id="tier_maximum_skus_0"> RM 
                            <input type="text" name="tier_cost_skus[]" id="tier_cost_skus_0">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" onclick="addSKUsTier(this)"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="result-cost-container">
                <label for="base_cost">Monthly (RM):</label><br>
                <label for="qty_sites">Yearly (RM):</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="script/calculator_function.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

But, it is only success in storing the value in the database when I don't add any tier. When I add a second tier, the button save is not getting triggered. Then, data is not being stored in the database.

Here the function:

```
document.getElementById('calculatorForm').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    saveData();
});

function addSitesTier(iconElement) {
    addTier(iconElement, 'sites');
    enableFormSubmission();
}

function addUsersTier(iconElement) {
    addTier(iconElement, 'users');
    enableFormSubmission();
}

function addSKUsTier(iconElement) {
    addTier(iconElement, 'skus');
    enableFormSubmission();
}

function addTier(container, type) {
    var tierContainer = document.getElementById(`${type}Container`);
    var lastTier = tierContainer.lastElementChild;

    // Get the index for the new tier
    var index = lastTier ? parseInt(lastTier.getAttribute('data-index')) + 1 : 0;

    // Create a new tier element
    var newTier = document.createElement('div');
    newTier.className = type + '-tier';
    newTier.setAttribute('data-index', index);

    // Create HTML content for the new tier
    var tierHTML = `<i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" onclick='removeTier(this, "${type}")'></i>
                    <input type="number" name="tier_minimum_${type}[]" required id="tier_minimum_${type}_${index}"> -
                    <input type="number" name="tier_maximum_${type}[]" required id="tier_maximum_${type}_${index}"> RM
                    <input type="text" name="tier_cost_${type}[]" id="tier_cost_${type}_${index}">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" onclick='addTier(this.parentNode, "${type}")'></i>`;

    // Set the HTML content for the new tier
    newTier.innerHTML = tierHTML;

    // Append the new tier to the container
    tierContainer.appendChild(newTier);

    // Enable the plus icon in the current tier
    container.lastElementChild.lastElementChild.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';

    // Save data after adding a tier
    saveData();
}

function removeTier(iconElement, type) {
    var typeContainer = document.getElementById(`${type}Container`);
    var tierToRemove = iconElement.parentNode;
    var indexToRemove = tierToRemove.getAttribute('data-index');

    // Enable the plus icon in the previous tier if it exists
    var previousTier = tierToRemove.previousElementSibling;
    if (previousTier) {
        var plusIcon = previousTier.querySelector('.fa-plus');
        if (plusIcon) {
            plusIcon.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
        }
    }

    // Remove the tier from the container
    typeContainer.removeChild(tierToRemove);

    // Update the data-index for remaining tiers
    var tiers = typeContainer.getElementsByClassName(`${type}-tier`);
    for (var i = 0; i < tiers.length; i++) {
        tiers[i].setAttribute('data-index', i);
    }
}

function enableFormSubmission() {
    document.getElementById('calculatorForm').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        saveData();
    });
}

function saveData() {
    var sites_tiersData = [];
    var users_tiersData = [];
    var skus_tiersData = [];

    var base_cost = document.getElementById('base_cost').value;
    var qty_sites = document.getElementById('qty_sites').value;
    var qty_users = document.getElementById('qty_users').value;
    var qty_skus = document.getElementById('qty_skus').value;

    // Extract data for sites
    extractTierData('sites', sites_tiersData);

    // Extract data for users
    extractTierData('users', users_tiersData);

    // Extract data for skus
    extractTierData('skus', skus_tiersData);

    var formDataObject = {
        base_cost: base_cost,
        qty_sites: qty_sites,
        qty_users: qty_users,
        qty_skus: qty_skus,
        sites_tiersData: sites_tiersData,
        users_tiersData: users_tiersData,
        skus_tiersData: skus_tiersData,
    };
    console.log(formDataObject);

    // Send data to the server using fetch
    fetch('/calculator/calculate', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formDataObject),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}

function extractTierData(type, tiersData) {
    var tiers = document.querySelectorAll(`.${type}-tier`);
    for (let i = 0; i < tiers.length; i++) {
        var tierData = {
            minimum: document.getElementById(`tier_minimum_${type}_${i}`).value,
            maximum: document.getElementById(`tier_maximum_${type}_${i}`).value,
            cost: document.getElementById(`tier_cost_${type}_${i}`).value,
        };
        tiersData.push(tierData);
    }
}
```

the router:

```
const express = require('express');
const pool = require('../database/database');
const calculatorRouter = express.Router();
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

calculatorRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('calculator');
});

calculatorRouter.post('/calculate', async (req, res) => {
    const loggedInName = req.session.userEmail;
    const costID = uuidv4();
    const { base_cost, qty_sites, qty_users, qty_skus, sites_tiersData, users_tiersData, skus_tiersData } = req.body;

    const formattedTimestamp = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
        timeZone: 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur',
        year: 'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        day: '2-digit',
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
    }).format(new Date());

    try {
        // Insert into costs
        const costsQuery = `
            INSERT INTO costs (id, base_cost, qty_sites, qty_users, qty_skus, created_at, created_by)
            VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7);
        `;
        const costsValues = [costID, base_cost, qty_sites, qty_users, qty_skus, formattedTimestamp, loggedInName];

        await pool.query(costsQuery, costsValues);

        console.log('sites_tiers:', sites_tiersData);
        console.log('users_tiers:', users_tiersData);
        console.log('skus_tiers:', skus_tiersData);
        // Insert into cost_sites_sites
        await insertTiers('cost_sites', sites_tiersData, loggedInName, formattedTimestamp);
        await insertTiers('cost_users', users_tiersData, loggedInName, formattedTimestamp);
        await insertTiers('cost_skus', skus_tiersData, loggedInName, formattedTimestamp);

        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Data saved successfully' });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error saving data:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});

async function insertTiers(tableName, tiers, createdBy, createdAt) {
    for (let i = 0; i < tiers.length; i++) {
        const tableID = uuidv4();  // Generate the tableID for each tier

        const tierQuery = `
            INSERT INTO ${tableName} (id, tier_minimum, tier_maximum, tier_cost, created_at, created_by)
            VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
        `;

        const tierValues = [tableID, tiers[i].minimum, tiers[i].maximum, tiers[i].cost, createdAt, createdBy];

        await pool.query(tierQuery, tierValues);
    }
}

module.exports = calculatorRouter;
```